# CSS three column layout fluidity

Tags: css, html

I'm currently working on a CSS three column layout (http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/rCtGd/) and I wanted to ask several questions:

1) For some strange reason there seems to be a 10px gap between the header, **content-1, content 2-1, content-2-2**. This cannot be seen in jsfiddle but if you load up the code in any browser it is noticeable. How do I get rid of it?

2) I would like to figure out a way of clearly defining a fluid column height. Is this possible? Ideally I would like all the divs **header, content-1, content 2-1, content-2-2, footer** to stretch in order to accommodate the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answers for your valid questions! :P

1. 10px gap is not found on the jsFiddle because, they use [**CSS Reset**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.
2. For getting a good idea about **CSS Fluid Layouts**, please refer the links below:

   - [The Perfect Fluid Width Layout](http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/)
   - [2 And 3 Column Fluid CSS Layouts](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/fluid-layout-code/)

Do you have any clarifications still? Let me know in the comments! :)